# join('') is not working unless I store it to a new variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state object which has a 'text' property as a string. I also have a remove handler method to deleting char which I click. If I do all job in one line, join('') is not working and React is storing it as an array, instead of string. But if I create a new variable for storing after join(''), it is working.

// this is storing into state as -> [h,e,y]

```
let textArr = [...this.state.text].splice(index, 1).join('');
this.setState({text: textArr});
```

// however this one works well, as -> 'hey'

```
    let textArr = [...this.state.text];
    textArr.splice(index, 1);
    let text = textArr.join('');
    this.setState({text});
```

Why is the first code is not working as expected but the second works?

Comment: `.splice` returns the deleted items

Comment: In other words, the docs are your friend: always verify your assumptions. In other other words, understand what your code is doing by asking yourself the question first, before asking someone else--likely the most important developer skill there is. (Followed closely by knowing the basics of regex and understanding recursion.)

Comment: Oh, and using the REPL (here, the JS console or just a NodeJS CLI REPL) to break down code chunks step-by-step so you can see, immediately, what's happening at each step of some code.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you apply `join` on the results of splice:

```
let textArr = [...this.state.text].splice(index, 1).join('');
```

it is equivalent to:

```
let str= [...this.state.text]
let temp = str.splice(index, 1)
let textArr = temp.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using splice here. The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s). So in the first line basically you are applying join on removed items. Ex. below

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
//here result will be equal to join of removed items
var result = [...arr1].splice(1,2).join('');
console.log(result) //it will give '23'
```

Now coming to you second logic. Here you are performing join on actual array not the returned array by splice(). See below example :

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var arr2 = [...arr1]; //value of arr2 now is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr2.splice(1,2); //value of arr2 now is [1, 4, 5, 6]
var result = arr2.join(''); 
console.log(result) //you will see "1456" in console
```

I hope it clarifies why first code didn't work as expected for you.